# Sweet alert is deleting only the first row

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

In my laravel project I am using sweet alert works fine but it is deleting my first-row record only I don't know what the problem is

this is my form

```
<td>                                    
<form id="myform" class="delete-photo" method="POST" action="{{route('testimony.destroy', $testimony->id)}}">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" data-photo-id="{{$testimony->id}}"
                class="submitdel btn btn-danger"
        >Delete</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my script

```
$('.delete-photo').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
    var linkURL = $(this).attr("action");
    warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL);
});

function warnBeforeRedirect(linkURL) {
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#5c5856",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                document.getElementById("myform").submit();
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: you are facing problem because your all record forms are having same id and you are submitting using ID, so by default first from will submitted

Comment: Generating N number of form for N record is not a good idea, you need to use Ajax for delete.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your form passing a same id each time. if you are looping in your record then the form must be loop thought. But this is not good practice. i would suggest you to use

```
<button type="submit" data-photo-id="{{$testimony->id}}" class="submitdel btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

in loop then the **$testimony->id** would be different with it's own id that is coming from database. Then get it's **data-photo-id** with Javascript on click event handler then pass this id to your controller and post the url.

okay suppor you are getting dynamic data from database and displaying it like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td><button type="submit" data-photo-id="1" class="submitdel btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td><button type="submit" data-photo-id="2" class="submitdel btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td><button type="submit" data-photo-id="3" class="submitdel btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then get the data-photo-id (replace this with your dynamic id) by using this way

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.submitdel').on('click',function(){
    // store current button into variable
    var id = $(this).data('photo-id');
    warnBeforeRedirect(id);
  })
})

function warnBeforeRedirect(id) {
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#5c5856",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                window.location = 'http://yoursite.com/controllername/'+id
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
            }
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

and replace **window.location** with the url you are want to use. Hope you get it now.

Comment: I have edited my post again check out and lemme know if still there any problem.

Comment: how can i set this dynamically for all of them to get the current delete url http://yoursite.com/controllername/

Comment: suppose you have a route like http://yoursite.com/testimony/destroy/dynamic-id just replace this dynamic field. this id would be dynamic and you will get this id in destroy method and  delete record on this id base. that's simple

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/testimony/destroy/16 i am getting this in the url and page not found

Comment: you have to write its route first

Comment: i want to use it for all my delete methods in my project as a master...is there any way how how to get the current delete url men

Comment: and this is my  route   Route::resource('testimony','Backend\TestimonialsController');

Comment: how can you do that? Let's assume you have 3,4 or more tables in db and you want to del record from table on id base then from another table on id base each table id would be different then how possibly you can use single delete function for all that delete request. this is all what i understood. Could you be more specific to your problem.

Comment: does that mean i have to mention the script in every view file ...like for blog delete, users delete....since i have to refer the window.location  route for each

Comment: obviously you have to call this function on each page where it is required. I don't this is much complicated task. This is just common practice.

Comment: ok so Route::resource('testimony','Backend\TestimonialsController'‌​); this is my testimony route, and how can i specify the url in the window.location for the testimony delete ...am sorry am a beginner at this

Comment: testimony is the route name any hit to this url will lead to Backend->TestimonialController->delete method i'll suggest to you custom route with params like id you are using resourceRouter at this time this will only handle the request that's is coming from it.